# For a function of two variables, how to show that it is not continous?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)= 2(x^3+y^3)/(x^2+2y)$ when (x,y)≠(0,0) and $f(x,y)=0$ when $(x,y)=(0,0)$. To show that the function is Not continous.

in order to show non continuity, i need to show that the value of function varies for different paths taken.
Book gives the hint of using $y=-x^2/2+mx^3$. but my question is, how am i suppose to use this path in competitive exams without the hint? cause generally we use $y=mx$ or $x=my^2$ etc.

Also, how can we can do questions like this by using polar coordinates?in this particular case, won't it be lengthy to use?

Comment: The best hint I can give you is this: trial and error. Yes, you can try the "standard" paths, and if those don't work, you should look at the function and try to see why it breaks. For example, in your exercise, the hint from the textbook is clearly trying to mess with the denominator, so that it goes to zero as a third power, while the numerator does so as a second power.

Comment: so, there is no trick used? how are we suppose to know in exams

Comment: Use your intuition... If there were a clear-cut recipe to solving every problem, maths would be the easiest subject ever, and also the most boring. Try and understand why the book gives that hint, and try to mess with functions and limits without feeling constrained by the exercises that a textbook may suggest. You'll quickly learn to spot what parts of a function make it behave well or badly, and how to manipulate them to show what you want to show.

Comment: okay, thank you @RiccardoOrlando